# How is PRG safe?

Tags: javascript, rest, networking

So like...Can any web developers explain to me how PRG makes things safer??? I see the "confirmation through redundancy" prinicipal at play, but I don't understand how they could counter-balance the risks.

As a network-dev I see an opportunity for someone to hijack the request or perform other kinds of man-in-the-middle attacks. If your site isn't HTTPS, or doesn't mandate the use of cookies, how could this be allowed?
[image: from wikipedia]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: The image on your question (the first image on the wiki) isn't PRG. [The _second_ image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get#/media/File:PostRedirectGet_DoubleSubmitSolution.png) on that wiki is the one with PRG.

Answer (score 0):

The POST-redirect-GET flow has nothing to do with security.

Its purpose is purely to work around a user interface issue: if a user presses the browser's "reload" button while viewing a page that was the result of a POST request, their POST request will be repeated. For requests that perform an action -- like posting a comment, or making a purchase -- this is often undesirable.

Performing a redirect to a GET request solves the problem: pressing "reload" will only repeat the GET request, not the POST.

Comment: Ok I made a bit of a leap in my phrasing, but corrupted data presents a security risk in complex systems.

Comment: There is no data corruption involved, though. And the only actor involved is the authorized user.

Comment: Isnt the PRG system designed to prevent malformed or omitted requests? And in a perfect world, you're definitely right about the only actor, but I see a race-condition presented by that refresh. Where am I wrong? (<<--serious question, not trying to goad)

Comment: @RobTruxal No. The PRG flow has no way to prevent requests from being corrupted or lost. There is a race condition of sorts if a user performs a reload during the initial POST. However, again, this isn't a security issue; the system is still doing exactly what it's supposed to do, given the user input.